# Sorting ActiveRecord Records by Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using postgres DB & I have an array of product ids: `[5, 4, 1, 2]`
then I invoked

`products = Product.where(:id => ids)`

Now result products sort after invoking `products.map(&:id)` is `[4, 1, 2, 5]`

**How can I sort the products using same sort of `ids` array?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not in a position to test but this should work...

```
ids = [5, 4, 1, 2]

products = Product.where(id: ids).order('array_position(?, products.id)', ids)
```

Comment: nice db implementation, not sure which is best when we only get low number of rows but cool anyway!

Comment: corrected answer `products = Product.where(id: ids).order("array_position(ARRAY[#{ids.join(',')}], products.id)")`

Comment: `products.id::int`. Rails's ids are big int now

Answer (score 2):

This would do because you have few rows:

```
ids = [5, 4, 1, 2] 
products = Product.where(id: ids)
products = ids.map {|id| products.select {|p| p.id == id }  }
```

Comment: @apneadiving thanks but I expect to get `ActiveRecord::Relation` but this will return an array.

Comment: sure thing @SteveTurczyn solution is what you need then :)